# Prevent ListView Item refresh when adding another Item dynamically using Android

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I am using `BaseAdapter` to bind Custom `ListView`. And I am adding Items dynamically. Each Item contains `TextView`, `EditText`, `Spinner`. It is working fine. But now issue is that if user selects any value from `Spinner`, add some data in `EditText` and then if he/she adds new item then it clears all values of filled up data.
So, I want to prevent this refresh of already added Items when add new Item. How to do this ?
**My Code :**

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> aaName = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map = null;

map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("Name", Name value);
aaName.add(map);
NameAdapter nameAdapter = new NameAdapter(getActivity(), aaName);
lvName.setAdapter(nameAdapter);

public class NameAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chiefcomment_view, null);

    TextView tvName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    Spinner spnTime = (Spinner) vi.findViewById(R.id.spnTime);
    EditText etSpecification = (EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.etSpecification);

    HashMap<String, String> name = new HashMap<String, String>();
    name = data.get(position);

    tvName.setText(name.get("Name"));

    // Time Spinner...
    ArrayList<String> Time = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        Time.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }
    aaTime = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, R.layout.small_spinner_view, Time);
    spnTime.setAdapter(aaTime);

    return vi;
    }
}
```

Comment: try removing if(convertView == null) check.

Comment: I already tried it but no effect.

Comment: you can extend your model to accommodate the unsaved data or store it somewhere else whatever suits you and in getview make sure the view does not have any unsaved data, if it has then display it

Comment: @SyedWaqas, can u give any example like this ?

Comment: `And I am adding Items dynamically.`. Then please show the code where you do that.

Comment: you need to store the values somewhere(on change) and restore it in getView ... fx in name["Specification"] you can store the value from etSpecification after it change and in getView you should set value from name["Specification"]